# Removing mspaint as default image viewer for all users on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I am working on a script that assigns remote apps as default programs for opening different types of files on a Windows Server 2016 Remote Desktop Session Host.

It works for file types that don't already have a default.

I am trying to change the default image viewer. However, my script ends up adding it as an open with "choice" for the user but ms paint is used by default on a double click from file explorer.

Here is an example of the explorer registry tree for `.jpg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpg]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpg\OpenWithList]
"a"="mspaint.exe"
"MRUList"="ab"
"b"="mstsc.exe"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpg\OpenWithProgids]
"jpegfile"=hex(0):

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpg\UserChoice]
"Hash"="Qw/OEl5uE2E="
"ProgId"="PBrush"
```

Can I simply delete the `.jpg` `OpenWithList` and `UserChoice` trees and replace it with this?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpg\OpenWithList]
"a"="mstsc.exe"
"MRUList"="a"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpg\UserChoice]
```

Will this make explorer open the jpegfile with the `mstsc.exe` program without prompting the user to make a selection?

Comment: No, but you can use [this](https://github.com/DanysysTeam/PS-SFTA) instead. It can get you in the right direction if it doesn't solve your issue completely.

Comment: Can you use the "**FTYPE**" commands? If you can, that would be be a much simpler option than hacking the registry. This is a good summation: [Setting Default Apps in Win10](https://superuser.com/questions/1519656/how-to-set-default-apps-on-windows-10-with-a-script)